# MobX and Firebase, TypeError: WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__firebase.b.ref is not a function

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, mobx, mobx-react

When a button is pushed, the recordUpvote function in the code below is called and returns this error:

Error: TypeError: **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__firebase**.b.ref is not a function
[image: the error]

I've tried exporting this function as a function and as a constant. When exporting as a constant, an error is thrown on the declaration of 'var Today = '.

I included the onceGetUsers function here because that function does work.

```
import { db } from './firebase';
import moment from 'moment';

export const onceGetUsers = () =>
  db.ref('users').once('value');

export function recordUpVote(instr, user) {
  var today = moment().format('MMDDYYYY');

  var rootRef = db.ref('/votes/' +today+ '/' +instr+ '/');
  rootRef.child('voters').orderByChild('user').equalTo(user).on("value", function(snapshot) {

      console.log(snapshot.val());

      if(snapshot.val()==null){
        // Record the vote
        db.ref('/votes/' +today+ '/' +instr+ '/voters/').push({
          user: user
            }).then(()=>{
             db.ref('/users/'+user+ '/votes/' + today+ '/').push({
               instrument: instr,
               vote: 'up'
             }).then(()=>{
               db.ref('/votes/' +today+ '/' +instr+ '/upVotes').transaction(function(upVotes) {
                 return upVotes + 1
               });
             });
        });
       }

      snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
          if(data.key==null){
            // Record the vote
            db.ref('/votes/' +today+ '/' +instr+ '/voters/').push({
              user: user
                }).then(()=>{
                 db.ref('/users/'+user+ '/votes/' + today+ '/').push({
                   instrument: instr,
                   vote: 'up'
                 }).then(()=>{
                   db.ref('/votes/' +today+ '/' +instr+ '/upVotes').transaction(function(upVotes) {
                     return upVotes + 1
                   });
                 });
            });
          } else {
            console.log("This user already voted on this instrument on this day. Update chart.")
          }
      });
  });

}
```

Updating post with the firebase.js code...

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/database';

const prodConfig = {
  };

const devConfig = {
  };

const config = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
  ? prodConfig
  : devConfig;

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
}

const db = firebase.database();
const auth = firebase.auth();

export {
  db,
  auth,
};
```

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing what your `./firebase.js` file looks like, but maybe the import is wrong? Maybe it should be `import db from './firebase';`?

Comment: @Tholle Thank you, I'm looking into these now, but I also added the code from './firebase' to the question.

Comment: Can the problem be that the database fields have not been added to the database (in the past it has just created them when invoked) ... or could the problem be that the fields have not been defined in the rules file?

Comment: I don't know, I'm afraid. You seem to have imported `app`, `auth` and `database` but `db.ref` is still not a function. I have no idea why that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by calling the function from the store. For example...

store.js

```
var today = moment().format('MMDDYYYY');
db.chartUpdate(ActiveSymbol, today, User)
```

db.js

```
export const chartUpdate = (symbol, today, user) => (
  console.log(symbol, today, user)
)
```